# Icons on the right side of the bootstrap navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

While doing some experimentation with twitter's bootstrap, I am trying to make a navbar with the Brand on the left side, the collapsing menu next to it, and finally a not-expanding set of icons on the right side.

Here's a  [diddly'fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zyr054he/):

And the problematic part :

```
      <!-- Non-collapsing right-side icons -->
      <div class="navbar-header navbar-right pull-right">
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">
            <img style="max-width:32; vertical-align:middle;" src="img/icon1.png">
          </a></li>
          <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">
            <img style="max-width:32; vertical-align:middle;" src="img/icon2.png">
          </a></li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!--/.navbar-right -->
```

As you can see in the fiddle, when the menu is collapsed, it's ok. But when the windows is large enough for the menu to expand, the icons are moved to the left (between the brand and the menu).

I also tried to put the non collapsing icons outside the navbar-header : in this case the expanded navbar is ok, but the collapsed version become wrong (the icons are in a different row).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to structure the html differently, use classes that are meant to be used on the navbar (pull-right and pull-left are not to be used in the navbar) and write custom css.

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/humoye/1/

Code: http://jsbin.com/humoye/1/edit

*Try not to use inline-styles, and do be sure to use correct syntax, use fonts instead of graphics if possible because raster images on retina devices it will look blurry  unless you load double the size and size it down in the css (or several other ways).*

**CSS**

```
/* icon */ .custom-navbar .fa {font-size:25px}

@media (max-width:767px) { 
    .custom-navbar .navbar-right {
        float: right;
        padding-right: 15px;
    }
    .custom-navbar .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li {
        float: right;
    }
    .custom-navbar .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li > a {
        padding:8px 5px;
    }
    .custom-navbar .navbar-toggle {
        float: left
    }
    .custom-navbar .navbar-header {
        float: left;
        width: auto!important;
    }
    .custom-navbar .navbar-collapse {
        clear: both;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top custom-navbar" role="navigation">
     <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-header">
           <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#" title="Help">
           Help ?
           </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Non-collapsing right-side icons -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
           <li>
             <a href="#" class="fa fa-cog"></a>
           </li>
           <li>
             <a href="#" class="fa fa-home"></a>
           </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- the collapsing menu -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left"  id="navbar-collapse-1">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
     </div>
     <!--/.container -->
  </nav>
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you Christina for the answer and for the lesson.

Also thank you for the extremely useful Awesome-font thing. 
That said, I dohave a question about that point: Wouldn't it be somehow too heavy to load a font with 479 icons just to use 4 or 5 ? 
Shouldn't I use some SVG's instead ?

Comment: @Enauofas - Bootstrap comes with Glyphicons, so you can see if what is available. Look at their docs. You can also just cut out all css, except for those fonts. The thing to do is to customize boostrap to save space there's gobs of CSS that you'll probably not use. Go to Customizer at their site.

Comment: You can use iconmoo to create your own icon font with fewer icons :)

Comment: The sample code have an issue: icons on the right reverse order when navbar collapses.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, **Menu** div should be inside **Header** div.

Also **Header** div should also have 100% width to retail position on any screen size.